# Configuring jira to run behind a proxy

Tags: jira

I am trying to install Jira into an LXC container. The container is on a machine which runs `nginx` as proxy. `nginx` is getting  requests that are incoming to `jira`  on port 443 and redirecting them to `jira's` container port 80 (`jira` is listening port 80 with help of authbind). Actually everything is working fine except that jira can not connect to Atlassian Market place. Here is my server.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener" />
    <!-- Prevent memory leaks due to use of particular java/javax APIs-->
    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />


    <Service name="Catalina">


        <Connector 
            acceptCount="100"
            connectionTimeout="20000" 
            disableUploadTimeout="true" 
            enableLookups="false" 
            maxHttpHeaderSize="8192" 
            maxThreads="150" 
            minSpareThreads="25" 
            port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
            redirectPort="8443"
            useBodyEncodingForURI="true" 
            scheme="https"
            proxyName="jira.ddos-guard.net" proxyPort="443"/> 


        <Connector port="80"

                   maxThreads="150"
                   minSpareThreads="25"
                   connectionTimeout="20000"
                   URIEncoding="UTF-8"
                   enableLookups="false"
                   maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
                   protocol="HTTP/1.1"
                   useBodyEncodingForURI="true"
                   redirectPort="8443"
                   acceptCount="100"
                   disableUploadTimeout="true"
                   bindOnInit="false"/>

<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener"
          SSLEngine="on" SSLRandomSeed="builtin" />


        <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
            <Host name="localhost" appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

                <Context path="" docBase="${catalina.home}/atlassian-jira" reloadable="false" useHttpOnly="true">              

                   <Resource name="UserTransaction" auth="Container" type="javax.transaction.UserTransaction"
                              factory="org.objectweb.jotm.UserTransactionFactory" jotm.timeout="60"/>
                    <Manager pathname=""/>
                    <JarScanner scanManifest="false"/>
                </Context>

            </Host>

            <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve"
        pattern="%a %{jira.request.id}r %{jira.request.username}r %t&quot;%m %U%q %H&quot; %s %b %D &quot;%{Referer}i&quot; &quot;%{User-Agent}i&quot; &quot;%{jira.request.assession.id}r&quot;"/>

        </Engine>
    </Service>
</Server>
```

This is what do I get while trying to tcpdump traffic that is going to MarketPlace's ip while I am searching for plugins

```
    09:01:24.208731 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 22452, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 67)
    jira.mydomain.net.60817 > mydns-address.domain: [bad udp cksum 0x4817 -> 0x8758!] 52973+ A? plugins.atlassian.com. (39)

09:01:24.210589 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 60, id 34505, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 83)
    mydns-address.domain > jira.mydomain.net.60817: [udp sum ok] 52973 q: A?
 plugins.atlassian.com. 1/0/0 plugins.atlassian.com. [55m46s] A 131.103.28.7 (55)
```

Comment: You should ask this question at http://superuser.com. It has nothing to do with programming, so it is off topic.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Atlassian Marketplace connectivity guide [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/UPM/Problems+Connecting+to+the+Atlassian+Marketplace), you may need to configure an outbound proxy with [these steps](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/how-to-configure-an-outbound-http-and-https-proxy-for-jira-applications-247857187.html)